# How to handle a UNIX domain socket connection with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix

Im trying to communicate a Node.js application with some C processes, I thought on UNIX sockets in order of performance, however I got a bit confused on how I should handle it.

I tried:

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = '/tmp/echo.sock';
fs.unlink(path, function () {
  var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
    console.log('server connected');
    c.on('end', function() {
      console.log('server disconnected');
    });

    c.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    c.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    c.write('hello\r\n');
    c.pipe(c);
  });
  server.listen(path, function() {
    console.log('server bound on %s', path);
  });
});
```

I ran it with sudo and it's listening, then I created this C client:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <sys/un.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define DATA "Half a league, half a league . . ."
 main(argc, argv)
     int argc;
     char *argv[];
 {
     int sock;
     struct sockaddr_un server;
     char buf[1024];
     if (argc < 2) {
         printf("usage:%s <pathname>", argv[0]);
         exit(1);
     }
     sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sock < 0) {
         perror("opening stream socket");
         exit(1);
     }
     server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
     strcpy(server.sun_path, argv[1]);
     if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) < 0) {
         close(sock);
         perror("connecting stream socket");
         exit(1);
     }
     if (write(sock, DATA, sizeof(DATA)) < 0)
         perror("writing on stream socket");
     close(sock);
 }
```

But any time I execute the C program by `sudo ./socket /tmp/echo.sock` it comes up to error at node:

```
{ [Error: write EPIPE] code: 'EPIPE', errno: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }
```

How should I implement this?

Comment: Does the `socket` file already exist?

Comment: Well I created a blank `socket` file via touch

Comment: I think that's your problem. `listen` needs to be able to create the socket file to listen on. Have a look [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3540) and [here](https://gist.github.com/dshaw/9f93cdcd3a77b9142e51). Either that or it's a permissions thing.

Comment: @BenFortune I already fixed that but I'm still lost on use of it. Could you check my update

Comment: @diegoaguilar I tested your node server code and it works as expected. I used netcat for writing to (and reading from) the unix socket.